# Open Source or Free PHP Based SSO Server

Tags: gratis, open-source, authentication

I am trying to find an SSO server written in PHP that is either open source or free which meets the following needs...

1. Authenticate users against multiple Samba directories
2. Get user groups from directory
3. Easy to use server side code for integrating into internal PHP software for authenticating users and getting the users groups
4. Easy to change the login form template to match website theme
5. Support for authenticating not just against sub domains of the same root domain but also cross domain support

As an example I am after something similar to the way Stack Exchange manages authentication across all stack exchange sites but in PHP not in .NET.

Thanks